# memory_get_usage() real_size is less than allocated size

Tags: php, memory

In php manual, I know that memory_get_usage(real_usage) Returns the amount of memory allocated to PHP, and set real_usage to TRUE to get total memory allocated from system, including unused pages.

I think, real usage should greater than allocated size. But my php script real usage less than allocated size and sometimes greater than allocated memory.

My code.

```
function p($var, $exit = false)
{
    $trace = debug_backtrace();
    $file = $trace[0]['file'];
    $line = $trace[0]['line'];
    if(is_bool($var)) {
        $str = $var ? 'true' : 'false';
    } else {
        $str = print_r($var, true);
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    echo $file . ' : ' . 'line #' . $line . '<br>';
    echo $str;
    echo '</pre>';
    if($exit)
        exit();
}
line 226: p(memory_get_usage());
line 227: p(memory_get_usage(true));
line 228: p(memory_get_peak_usage());
line 229: p(memory_get_peak_usage(true));
```

Result:

[real usage less than allocated memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkUDC.jpg)

[real usage greater than allocated memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeJ5v.jpg)

I wonder why this happens. Thanks for help.

Comment: What was done differently between the two screenshots?  I'm assuming this is Windows based on the slash direction?

Comment: First screenshot , the real usage is 2097152B and allocated memory is 8124592B. Second screenshot ,the real usage is 10485760B and allocated memory is  8126512B.